# How to use JWT token stored in cookie on a NodeJs API using Fetch API Get Request in ReactJs to get user data

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Hi I have managed to store the JWT token generated on Login to a cookie in the browser. How can I use the token to display a list of users from a protected route in Nodejs APi.

I have accessed the token from the cookie using following code

```
Cookies.get("access")
```

the Fetch API Code is

```
const url = "http://localhost:4000/users/";

  const getUsers = () => {
    fetch(
      url,
      { method: "GET" },
      {
        headers: {
          Authorization: "Bearer" + Cookies.get("access"),
          "x-auth-token": Cookies.get("access"),
        },
      }
    )
      .then((data) => data.json())
      .then((prdt) => console.log(prdt));
  };

  useEffect(getUsers, []);
```

Node API Code is as follows:

```
//http://localhost:4000/users

router.get("/", auth, async function (request, response) {
  try {
    const result = await getAllUsers();
    response.send(result);
  } catch {
    response.status(400).send({
      message: error,
    });
  }
});
```

the Nodejs Auth Code is as follows:

```
export const auth = (request, response, next) => {
  try {
    const token = request.header("x-auth-token");
    console.log("token", token);
    jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET_KEY);
    next();
  } catch (err) {
    response.status(401).send({
      error: err.message,
    });
  }
};
```

I am not sure where I am going wrong

the Nodejs Part works as tried in Postman The issue is originating on the react side fetch API  where I am not sure how to send the keyname "x-auth-token" with jwt token to retrieve the data.

[image]

Comment: Can you be more specific? I’m confused what you are asking. Which part are you having trouble with? What’s the error you are encountering?

Comment: I am having trouble with the fetch api get request... I am unable to use the JWT token generated to access a nodejs API. Basically I need to send the token to header with keyname "x-auth-token" to authenticate and retrieve the data. Included the postman screenshot to show what I mean

Comment: What error are you getting exactly? Is it not reading the token properly? What’s the error message/output right now?

Comment: There is no error displayed its completely blank... Issue may be I am not correctly passing the token through the header... But I am not sure how to correct it

Comment: Can you add a catch block to the chain and console log the error?  Sorry. It’s just hard for me to help you when it’s not clear where the error is coming from.

Comment: I figured out what the issue was. Something went wrong with the router and I had to restart the app to clear it... It's working as it is supposed to right now. Thank you for the assistance...

Comment: Cool. Glad to help.